# Copy value from one column based on the value of another column

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm trying to fill values in one column from two other columns based on the values in a fourth column.

I have a pandas dataframe with four columns: A, B, C, D

```
df_copy = df.copy()
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if 'Test' in row.D:
        df_copy.loc[i, 'A'] = row.B
    elif 'Other' in row.D:
        df_copy.loc[i, 'A'] = row.C
```

This works, but is very slow. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Does your row D only consist of 'Test' and 'Other'?

Comment: Row D consists of a longer string that contains either 'Test' or 'Other'

Comment: Ah, in that case you can use `str.contains`, updated my answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use 'boolean indexing' for this instead of iterating over all rows:

```
df_copy.loc[df['D']=='Test', 'A'] = df['B']
df_copy.loc[df['D']=='Other', 'A'] = df['C']
```

If you know that column D only consists of these two values, it can even shorter:

```
df_copy['A'] = df['B']
df_copy.loc[df['D']=='Other', 'A'] = df['C']
```

If you want to have the same as the `in` operator to test if that substring is in the column, you can do:

```
df['D'].str.contains('Other')
```

to become the boolean values instead of the `df['D']=='Other'`

Comment: This works, with the caveat that you can't use the 'in' boolean test.