# Pandas Copy value based on Match

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string-matching

In a csv file with 5 columns, I am trying to copy a value in one of the 2columns, in case there is a match of specific string, related to that column.

First the csv file looks as below

```
# 'Test.csv'

col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
alex    str1    47  0   54
beth    str2    94  94  0
stan    str1    18  0   18
hank    str1    37  0   37
june    str1    84  0   84
mary    str2    34  34  0
```

Simply put,

if 'col2' value is 'str1', then only 'col4' is filled with value of 'col3',
(or)
if 'col2' value is 'str2', then only 'col5' is filled with value of 'col3'.

The code which seemed very close to my answer, was in this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29991862/copy-value-from-one-column-based-on-the-value-of-another-column), but I am unable to modify it for the data above.

[Copy value from one column based on the value of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29991862/copy-value-from-one-column-based-on-the-value-of-another-column)

Comment: What was solution from linked answer? What was problem with solutuion? It should working well.

Comment: Hi @jezrael , it shows answer as this: "df_copy.loc[df['D']=='Test', 'A'] = df['B']", but I was able to do this so far, "df.loc[df["col2"]=='str1', "  I am not following what is 'A' in that solution...sorry Im a total rookie...

Comment: So need `df_copy.loc[df_copy['col2']=='str1', 'col4'] = df_copy['col3']
df_copy.loc[df_copy['col2']=='str2', 'col5'] = df_copy['col3']` ?

Comment: Thank you so much @jezrael , can you please make that as an answer, so I can mark your answer as solution... thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df_copy.loc[df_copy['col2']=='str1', 'col4'] = df_copy['col3']    
df_copy.loc[df_copy['col2']=='str2', 'col5'] = df_copy['col3']
```

It means if matching condition then set `col4` or `col5` by values of column `col3`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need two lines of code:

```
df['col4'] = np.where(df.col2 == 'str1', df.col3, df.col4)
df['col5'] = np.where(df.col2 == 'str2', df.col3, df.col5)
```

Comment: Oh thanks @Rajesh Bhat ... this solution works perfectly.. But I guess I will need to include the np library.. I was hoping a pure pandas way to work as there are many function in use at once, and wanted memory efficiency...